# Find initial condition so that ODE has multiple solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Given Cauchy problem
$$y'=\dfrac{x^2}{y(1+x^3)}, \;y(x_0)=y_0.$$
Is it possible to find $(x_0,y_0)$ such that given Cauhcy problem has multiple solutions?
It is obvious that equation is with separable variables and I got solution $y^2=\dfrac{2}{3}\ln |c(1+x^3)|$. If we use theorem of existence and uniqueness I conclude equation have unique solution for $(x_0,y_0)\in  \big[(\infty,-1)\cup(-1,\infty)\big]\times\big[(\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\big]$. For any other $(x_0,y_0)$ ODE is not defined.
Is my conclusion wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $y$: $$yy'=\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}$$Integrate both sides by $x$: $$\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{\ln(|x^3+1|)}{3}+
C$$The integral of $yy'$ is obtained by making a $u$-substitution. The other integral is obtained by making a $u$-substitution of $x^3$. Now solve for $y$: $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\ln(|x^3+1|)+C}$$So there are at least two solutions.

Comment: i think your $y$ is same as mine, every constant $c$  can be written in form $\ln |c_1|$ for some $c_1$. You are saying that there are always two solutions, but that contradicts theorem.

Comment: @Mark this means that the theorem is wrong?

Comment: @Mark your $y^2$ was right, sorry about that. If you take the root of both sides you get a plus or minus, meaning there are at least two solutions.

Comment: No, there is only one solution for each initial value. $C$ is completely determined by the initial point and the sign before the root has to be equal to the sign of $y_0$.

Comment: You mean there is one solution for $y^2$?

Comment: @lutzlehmann In area pointed out in the question solution is unique, outside of it isn't well defined so there is no solution. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One could also say that the sign of the root depends on the part of the domain that the initial point and thus the whole solution lives in.